# FCM notification message not received/displayed after application has been dead for a while

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am in the process of developing a video call app, and I am using FCM push notifications to warn the user of incoming calls. I.e, these notifications should show up no matter the state of the app (except of course 'force stopped'). This works fine while the application is running and also after i killed it manually from the recent apps screen. However, if the application has been dead for some time (ex. 24 hours), the notifications do not get displayed. I am unable to find documentation for how this is supposed to work.